# JPA OneToOne relation doesnt persist child entity when saving parent

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I'm having problems with automatically persisting my child entity when persisting the parent. I have followed guides etc but can't seem to find where I'm making a mistake.

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mp_item")
public class Item {

@BatchFetch(value = BatchFetchType.JOIN)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ItemGroupSuggestion itemGroupSuggestion; 
}
```

Child:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "mp_itemgroup_suggestion")
public class ItemGroupSuggestion  {

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
private Item item;
```

When creating a suggestion I am setting the reference to the parent, and in the parent the reference to the child, like this:

```
ItemGroupSuggestion suggestion = new ItemGroupSuggestion(item, itemgroups, nearestItem);
// sets this.item = item inside constructor of ItemGroupSuggestion
item.setItemGroupSuggestion(suggestion);
```

After setting the references, I do a batch-save:

```
itemService.saveAll(items);
```

Why are the children not getting persisted?

Comment: Why ins't their any `@Id` into your entity ?

Comment: @Zorglube I omitted it because it deemed it not relevant, it's done in a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter in item should be as follows:

```
public void setItemGroupSuggestion(ItemGroupSuggestion itemGroupSuggestion) {
    itemGroupSuggestion.setItem(this);
    this.itemGroupSuggestion = itemGroupSuggestion;
}
```

Comment: My setter does not look like that, but in practice I do the same thing. Whenever I create a suggestion, I set the Item in the suggestion-class, and then I set the suggestion in the Item-class, and that should accomplish the same thing right?

Comment: yes, if that the case you need to show more code such as how you are populating your entities before saving and transactional boundaries etc

Comment: I updated the question with more code, showing how I populate the entities. Regarding the transactional boundaries I'm not exactly sure what's relevant there. If you have anything specific you want to know then I'll provide it. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I finally got it to work, for some reason when I provided the **referencedColumnName** it started working. I thought that would be the default, but apparently not.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Item item;
```

If anyone knows why this was needed to get things working, please let me know.

Comment: It tell Hibernate (or any ORM) how is made the `SQL` junction. `@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id") private Item item;` That mean, in SQL : `mp_itemgroup_suggestion.item_id` is a foreingKey of `mp_item.id`.

Comment: It should have defaulted if the "id" column in Item is annotated as the ID and it isn't a composite ID. There is no need for it otherwise: Having the wrong value should still have let this 'work' using the ID field or throw exceptions; eclipseLink doesn't ignore bad mappings and will validate and let you know about them - turn on logging though and it might help explain what is happening.